# Is (x - x) always positive zero for doubles, or sometimes negative zero?

Tags: java, floating-point

When `x` is a `double`, is `(x - x)` guaranteed to be `+0.0`, or might it sometimes be `-0.0` (depending on the sign of `x`)?

Comment: tested: https://ideone.com/aT04yc

Comment: @Absurd-Mind Great, now test all the other `double`s! ;)

Comment: Well @AbsurdMind answered your question - not always. Also I'm wondering, what is the case where you need to know that?

Comment: @ST3 Well I don't really care about NaN, so the answer is actually yes, always +0 if x is finite. It matters when used in `atan2`!

Comment: You also have to take into account that another thread can possibly change the value of x.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`x - x` can be `+0.0` or `NaN`. There are no other values it can take in IEEE 754 arithmetics in round-to-nearest (and in Java, the rounding mode is [always round-to-nearest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.8.1)). The subtraction of two identical finite values is *defined* as producing `+0.0` in this rounding mode. [Mark Dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson), in comments below, cites the IEEE 754 standard as saying, section 6.3:

> When the sum of two operands with opposite signs (or the difference of two operands with like signs) is exactly zero, the sign of that sum (or difference) shall be +0 in all rounding-direction attributes except roundTowardNegative [...].

This [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) shows that in particular `0.0 - 0.0` and `-0.0 - (-0.0)` are both `+0.0`.

Infinities and NaN both produce NaN when subtracted from themselves.

Comment: Can you explain why round-to-nearest implies that `+0.0` is the only possibility (when `NaN`s and `Inf`s aren't involved)? And where is it documented that Java always uses round-to-nearest?

Comment: @jtbandes It is not so much that round-to-nearest *implies* that +0.0 is the result, it is just that the result of both subtractions is defined this way in round-to-nearest (but is not defined this way for other rounding modes). Regarding the rounding mode, my source is http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/JAVAhurt.pdf

Comment: @jtbandes: The sign of the zero is specified explicitly in the IEEE 754 standard, section 6.3: "When the sum of two operands with opposite signs (or the difference of two operands with like signs) is exactly zero, the sign of that sum (or difference) shall be +0 in all rounding-direction attributes except roundTowardNegative [...]"

Answer (score 9):

The SMT solver Z3 supports IEEE floating point arithmetic. Let's ask Z3 to find a case where `x - x != 0`. It immediately finds `NaN` as well as `+-infinity`. Excluding those, there is no `x` that satisfies that equation.

```
(set-logic QF_FPA)    

(declare-const x (_ FP 11 53))
(declare-const r (_ FP 11 53))

(assert (and 
    (not (= x (as NaN (_ FP 11 53))))
    (not (= x (as plusInfinity (_ FP 11 53))))
    (not (= x (as minusInfinity (_ FP 11 53))))
    (= r (- roundTowardZero x x))
    (not (= r ((_ asFloat 11 53) roundTowardZero 0.0 0)))
))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Z3 implements IEEE floating point arithmetic by converting all operations to boolean circuits and using the standard SAT solver to find a model. Barring any bugs in that translation or the SAT solver the result is perfectly precise.

Proof for...

- ...`roundTowardZero`: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/7H4
- ...`roundNearestTiesToEven`: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/Opl4W

Note the counterexample for the rounding mode `roundTowardNegative`: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/T845. For a certain `x` the result of `x - x` is negative zero. Such a case can hardly be found by humans. Yet, with an SMT solver it is easy to find. We can change `=` to `==` so that Z3 uses IEEE equality comparison semantics instead of exact equality. After that change, there is again no counter-example because `-0 == +0` according to IEEE.

I tried making the rounding mode a variable. That would work in theory but Z3 has a bug here. For now we have to manually specify a hard-coded rounding mode. If we could make it a variable we could ask Z3 to prove this statement for *all* rounding modes in one query.

Comment: Neat. But I'm getting `Z3(15, 10): ERROR: model is not available`

Comment: @jtbandes a model would indicate a counter-example to our theory. Since no counter-example is available we have no model and the theory holds. I have edited out the get-model call.

Comment: Don't you want `roundNearestTiesToEven` instead of `roundTowardZero`?

Comment: Shouldn't one have to find a case where 1/(x-x) != 1/0.0?  Otherwise, I think (-1 * 0.0) would compare equal to 0.0, would it not?

Comment: @supercat `=` compares exactly, `==` according to the IEEE standard. http://rise4fun.com/Z3/UgPo Play with the two assertions and comment one of them in.